# What package \isp macro from?

Tags: macros, packages, tools

What package macro `\isp` comes from? 
As I understood, there is not way not get such infomation quick, reliable way.
I hope I am wrong.

EDIT: My problem is that I have legacy code, that used a very ancient versions of
everything. Now I have a take to build it on moder LaTeX environment.
It looks like inverted by vertical `\Phi`.

Comment: Do you have such a LaTeX document that contains this command? If so, remove all from it except the `\isp` command, try removing the package imports one by one, until the `\isp` gives an error as being undefined.

Comment: http://lmgtfy.com/?q=ctan+%22%5Cisp%22 -- So no package available.

Comment: Anybody is allowed to define macros with any name. Try and make the question more precise, please.

Comment: Well, `\Phi` is symmetrical both in the horizontal and in the vertical directions. Is it `\Omega`, perhaps?

Comment: Looking at the name and the description you gave, perhaps it's an inverted [psi](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psi_(letter))? Something like `\usepackage{graphicx}

\newcommand\isp{\rotatebox{180}{$\psi$}}`?